# quickly make Layout background color interval appear in xml in android?

Tags: android, xml, background-color, intervals

Like there are many vertical lineLayout ,which background is black then is white ,then is black ,white......
how to create it quickly in xml or programmaly in android?

like this :

```
<LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
   android:background="@color/white"/>

   <LinearLayout
   android:background="@color/black"/>

   <LinearLayout
   android:background="@color/white"/>

   <LinearLayout
   android:background="@color/black"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add this line in your layout tag - android:background="#FFFFFF"

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're looking for?  I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking.

Comment: use `setBackground` in a loop with a `ColorDrawable` parameter

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to do it is through XML as shown below.
As long as you are not going to modify the background in run time, set it through Xml,  like this  :

```
<LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
   android:background="@color/white"/>

   <LinearLayout
   android:background="@color/black"/>

   <LinearLayout
   android:background="@color/white"/>

   <LinearLayout
   android:background="@color/black"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is this what you meant?

Comment: yes,that's what i mean.but how to create it quickly ,cause i have many many LinearLayout like this

Comment: so this is your answer.